# Facebook default like and share buttons for users not logged in - trouble

Tags: facebook

The question is simple... I copied Facebook code for like and share buttons. The problem is that when someone is not logged in Facebook account, these buttons shows text-only links "log in". How can i change them to "default" Facebook button with blue color and text "Login to like" or "Login to share". Thanks in advance!

Comment: What do you have those buttons pointed to? If it is a Facebook Page, and that page is not publicly visible or access to it restricted in any way, that is expected behavior.

Comment: Yep i noticed after.It is a Facebook issun. When you loggen in as a "page" and you go in a website, you don't see buttons only text "log in" .